# Facebook Graph API albums filtering by name

Tags: api, facebook

If I want to retrieve albums that contain the string "HELLO" in their name, I try to use the "filtering" parameter. However, all albums are returned in the result.

For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{page_id}/albums?filtering=[{field:"name",operator:"CONTAIN",value:"HELLO"}]&access_token={access_token}
```

How can I use "filtering" correctly?

Comment: Not all endpoints support filtering, and I don't see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/albums saying anywhere that this one actually would.